# filling div element with the background color and removing space between the div

Tags: html, css

Im a beginner in HTML/CSS and i would like to create a simple profile for my project in school. How can i do something like these image:
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B22cx.png)

I want to get rid of the problems that i'm explaining in the image. I'm stuck doing and changing my css since this is only a css problem.Here is what i've done:

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box-nav">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle-navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Welcome</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="border">
                <div class="box-1"></div>
                <div class="box-2"></div>
            </div>              
      </div>
      <div class="box-particle">
        <div id="particles-js">
            <h1>Hello, </h1>                
        </div>          
      </div>



      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper{
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.box{
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;  
}
.navbar {
  background-color:#000;
  display: inline-block;  
  width: 100%;  
  height: 10vh;
}
nav {
  height: 10vh;  
}
.navbar-nav {
  margin:auto;
}
.nav-link {
  margin:10px 25px;
  color:#fff;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  color:yellow;
}
.border {
  width:100%;
  height:25px;  
  float: left;  
  top: -2px;
  margin:0;  
  background-color:transparent;
  position:relative;    
  z-index: 1;
}
.box-1 {  
  width:50%;  
  height:100%;
  border-radius:0px 40px 0px 0px;
  border-top:5px solid yellow;
  border-right:5px solid yellow;   
}
.box-2 {
  position:absolute;  
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  border-radius:40px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-top:5px solid yellow;
  border-left:5px solid yellow;  
}
.box-nav{
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;  
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}

.box-particle{    
  position: absolute;
  top:9vh;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;  
}
#particles-js {
  position: relative;   
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url(background.jpg);*/
  /*background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.5);*/
  background-color: blue;
  height: 105vh;  
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin:0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#particles-js h1 {
  position: relative;
  top:47%;
  color:yellow;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 90vh !important;  
  width: 100% !important;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap? if yes which version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by seeing your classes, I assumed that you are using bootstrap 4, and here is the desired output you want.

don't use absolute position too much. use it when necessary.

to check your desired result just open this on bigger screen as you have used collapse LG in your code,

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper{
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.box{
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;  
}
.navbar {
  background-color:#000;
  display: inline-block;  
  width: 100%; 
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin:auto;
}
.nav-link {
  margin:10px 25px;
  color:#fff;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  color:yellow;
}
.border {
     width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  border: 0 !important;
}
.box-1 {  
  width:50%;  
  height:100%;
  border-radius:0px 40px 0px 0px;
  border-top:5px solid yellow;
  border-right:5px solid yellow;   
}
.box-2 {
  position:absolute;  
  height:100%;
  width:50%;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  border-radius:40px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-top:5px solid yellow;
  border-left:5px solid yellow;  
}
.box-nav{
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;  
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}

.box-particle{    
  position: absolute;
  top:9vh;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;  
}
#particles-js {
  position: relative;   
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url(background.jpg);*/
  /*background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.5);*/
  background-color: blue;
  height: 105vh;  
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin:0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#particles-js h1 {
  position: relative;
  top:47%;
  color:yellow;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 90vh !important;  
  width: 100% !important;
  background-attachment:fixed;
}

@media(max-width:991px){
  .box-nav .border {display: none;}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box-nav">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle-navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Welcome</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="border">
                <div class="box-1"></div>
                <div class="box-2"></div>
            </div>              
      </div>
      <div class="box-particle">
        <div id="particles-js">
            <h1>Hello, </h1>                
        </div>          
      </div>



      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the trick just playing with colors. It wont remove the arrow container's height, but may look like what you want. Example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10vh;
}

nav {
  height: 10vh;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin: auto;
}

.nav-link {
  margin: 10px 25px;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: yellow;
}

.myBorder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  float: left;
  top: -2px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom:-2px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-color:black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box-1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0px 40px 0px 0px;
  border-top: 5px solid yellow;
  border-right: 5px solid yellow;
  background-color:blue;
}

.box-2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 40px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-top: 5px solid yellow;
  border-left: 5px solid yellow;
  background-color:blue;
}

.box-nav {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
}

.box-particle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 9vh;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

#particles-js {
  position: relative;
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url(background.jpg);*/
  /*background-color: rgb(0,0,0,0.5);*/
  background-color: blue;
  height: 105vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  margin: 0;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#particles-js h1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 47%;
  color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  height: 90vh !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="box-nav">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-content" aria-controls="navbar-content" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle-navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Welcome</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="myBorder">
                <div class="box-1"></div>
                <div class="box-2"></div>
            </div>              
      </div>
      <div class="box-particle">
        <div id="particles-js">
            <h1>Hello, </h1>                
        </div>          
      </div>



      <div class="box">

      </div>
      <div class="box">

      </div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I hadded a black background to the `.border` element, and a blue one to both `.box-1` and `.box-2` elements.
Adjusting some settings to remove the white border would do the trick.

Comment: thanks. how can i remove the box1 and box2 white space like what i saw in your answer?

Comment: As the class .border has a `1px width` set to `!important` in bootstrap, it's a bit tricky to override. I juste renamed class `.border` to `.myBorder` in both HTML and CSS, this way, no border is applied. I added negative margin as well to prevent `top:-2px` to create a gap. see the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion consists of four steps:

1. Add the CSS rule `.navbar {margin:auto;}`
2. Remove `top: -2px` from the class `.border`
3. Change the background color of the `.border` class to `#000000`
4. Change the border color of the `.border` class to `#000000`. If you are using indeed Bootstrap4, this step needs a bit of a more specific rule to override the default style of Bootstrap, so it would be like:

   ```
   .wrapper .box-nav .border {
       border: 1px solid #000000 !important;
   }
   ```